# Jquery display none default not working

Tags: jquery, html

I basically want an admin toolbar, it will have a button that can be clicked to display is (adminbarplus) and on click it will slidedown the toolbar and slideup the adminbarplus, as the admin toolbar has its own hide button (adminbarminus). However, I need the bar to be hidden by default and adding inline HTML to display none doesn't work as it is replaced with display: block by default.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="row adminbar" id="adminbar" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row adminbaroverlay">
            <div class="large-2 columns">
                <div class="row valign-middle">
                    <div class="large-12 columns content2 adminbarsidebar">
                        <%= image_tag('admintitle.png') %>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-9 columns">
            <div class="row valign-middle">
                <div class="large-12 columns adminbarsidebar">
            <p class="margin0b padding0b margin0t padding0t"><span class="adminbutton">Manage Users</span>
            <span class="adminbutton">Manage Branches</span>
            <span class="adminbutton">Manage News</span></p>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns adminarrow" id="adminbarminus">
            <div class="row valign-middle">
                <div class="large-12 columns adminbarsidebar text-center">
                    <a href="#"><%= image_tag('minusicon.png') %></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<span class="adminbarplus">ADMIN BAR</span>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
             $("#adminbarminus").click(function(){
                $("#adminbar").slideUp();
                $(".adminbarplus").slideDown();
             });

             $(".adminbarplus").click(function(){
                $("#adminbar").slideDown();
                $(".adminbarplus").slideUp();
             });
```

Would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: It works me fine, in this code there is no problem - http://jsfiddle.net/5eLd4L2h/

Comment: Yes the specificity of that hidden should not have something else overriding it - where is the override coming from? Have you used a browser inspector to see?

Comment: Possibly missing information here - is this also using bootstrap or some other framework like it?

Comment: @DannyStaple Foundation 4

Answer (score 1):

```
         $("#adminbar").click(function(){
            $("#adminbar").slideUp();
            $(".adminbarplus").slideDown();
         });

         $(".adminbarplus").click(function(){
            $("#adminbar").slideDown();
            $(".adminbarplus").slideUp();
         });
```

your giving the wrong id.......
http://jsfiddle.net/z817oy53/

Answer (score 1):

Highly reccomend to you do not use jquery for animation or something like that, just do that with CSS3 transition or animation and use jQuery only for switching classes.

```
<div id="bar">
    <span class="minus">minus</span>
</div>

<span class="plus">plus</span>

<style>
    #bar{
        transition: transform .5s ease;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    #bar.isActive{
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
</style>

<script>

   $(function(){

       var bar = $("#bar"),
           plus = $(".plus"),
           minus = $(".minus");

       plus.click(function(){
           bar.addClass("isActive");
       });
       minus.click(function(){
           bar.removeClass("isActive");
       });

   });
</script>
```